# (Python3.x)Splitting arrays and saving them into new arrays

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, indexing

I'm writing a Python script intended to split a big array of numbers into equal sub-arrays. For that purpose, I use Numpy's split method as follows:

```
test=numpy.array_split(raw,nslices)
```

where *raw* is the complete array containing all the values, which are *float64*-type by the way.
*nslices* is the number of sub-arrays I want to create from the *raw* array.

In the script, *nslices* may vary depending of the size of the *raw* array, so I would like to "automatically" save each created sub-arrays in a particular array as : `resultsarray(i)`in a similar way that it can be made in MATLAB/Octave.
I tried to use a`for in range` loop in Python but I am only able to save the last sub-array in a variable.

What is the correct way to save the sub-array for each each incrementation from 1 to  `nslices`?

Here, the complete code as is it now (I am a Python beginner, please  bother the low-level of the script).

```
import numpy as np
file = open("results.txt", "r")
raw = np.loadtxt(fname=file, delimiter="/n", dtype='float64')
nslices = 3

rawslice = np.array_split(raw,nslices)

for i in range(0,len(rawslice)):
  resultsarray=(rawslice[i])
  print(rawslice[i])
```

Thank you very much for your help solving this problem!

Comment: Why don't you simply use `resultarray = np.array_split(raw, nslices)`? You can just use `resultarray[i]` after that step...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you screwed up delimiter :)
It should be backslash+n `\n` instead of `/n`.

Second - as Serge already mentioned in comment you can just access to split parts by index (`resultarray[0]` to `[2]`). But if you really wanted to assign each part to a separate variable you can do this in fommowing way:

```
result_1_of_3, result_2_of_3, result_3_of_3 = rawslice

print(result_1_of_3, result_2_of_3, result_3_of_3)
```

But probably it isn't the way you should go.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer Tupteq !
Indeed that's completely true ! :) 
In fact, the next part of the script is to set a table in a UI using the splitted arrays so that could be a solution if the nslices would remain constant. But still I keep it in mind if needed !